# Generate output on change of value or at end of stream

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, language-agnostic, text-processing

It is a common problem to have to read an input stream and generate a line of output if one of the columns changes value or when the end of the stream is reached. This generally requires two identical output statements which have to be wrapped in a subroutine to create a DRY solution

Here's a pseudo-code representation of what I mean

```
for line in file

    unpack line to data

    if data starts new group
        if aggregate_data
            display aggregate_data
            empty aggregate data
        end
    end

    add data to aggregate_data

end

if aggregate_data
    display aggregate_data
    empty aggregate data
end
```

And the usual solution is to write this as

```
for line in file

    unpack line to data

    if data starts new group
        flush_data
    end

    add data to aggregate_data

end

flush_data


subroutine flush_data
    if aggregate_data
        display aggregate_data
        empty aggregate data
    end
end
```

I wonder if this problem has a name, if any work has been done on it, and if an approach has been identified that allows this to be coded neatly

Comment: What do you mean in "subroutine", and can you show us the common problem?

Comment: @TechWisdom: I've written some pseudo-code. Let me know if it's unclear

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want to sort the entries in this file by *who does what*.

```
Alice tests
Alice bugfixes
Alice design
Bob documentation
Bob interface
Carol optimization
Carol refactoring
```

We could write the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char name[20];
    char task[20];
    char old_name[20];
    char task_list[20][10];
    int i = 0, j;

    strcpy(old_name, "");

    while (scanf("%19s %19s", name, task) != EOF) {
        if (strcmp(old_name, "") && strcmp(name, old_name)) {
            // Changed groups; print task list
            printf("%s's task list:\n", old_name);
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                printf(" - %s\n", task_list[j]);
            i = 0;
        }

        strcpy(old_name, name);
        strcpy(task_list[i++], task);
    }
}
```

Let's look at the output:

```
Alice's task list:
 - tests
 - bugfixes
 - design
Bob's task list:
 - documentation
 - interface
```

Oops, this has a bug in it! We print our `task_list` when `old_name` and `name` differ, but this means our final group remains unprinted.

Like the OP said, we could repeat our printing work after the while loop -- and optionally move it into a subroutine to make things a *little* nicer -- but is there a better way?

One option is to move your condition into a variable, and execute another half-a-loop (printing unconditionally) when you would normally call it quits:

```c
bool done;
while (true) {
    done = (scanf("%39s %39s", name, task) == EOF);
    if (done || (strcmp(old_name, "") && strcmp(name, old_name))) {
        // Do printing...
    }

    if (done)
        break;

    strcpy(old_name, name);
    strcpy(task_list[i++], task);
}
```

Of course, I picked a low-level language like C for a reason :) In languages that provide you with the right tools, you can often avoid these annoying details by expressing your logic on a higher level. Here's a Python script as an example:

```python
from itertools import groupby
import sys

entries = [line.split() for line in sys.stdin]

for name, group in groupby(entries, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    tasks = [x[1] for x in group]
    print("{0}'s task list:".format(name))
    for task in tasks:
        print(' - ' + task)
```